# python - how to run a function on last day of every month?

Tags: python

I have a python function and I want to run the function on last day of the every month.

how can i do that?

Comment: This is very platform dependant... and it won't be a feature of python. For example on linux you can use cron

Answer (score 3):

This calls for the use of a cron job or a similiar scheduling application.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=`/bin/date +%d`
TOMORROW=`/bin/date +%d -d "1 day"`

# See if tomorrow's day is less than today's
if [ $TOMORROW -lt $TODAY ]; then
        exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

Now we can add this line to your crontab (which can be accessed by `crontab -e`

```
12 0 * * * last-day-of-month.sh && /usr/bin/python /location/of/my/python/script
```

If you are using Windows you can use the commandline tool schtasks with the argument LASTDAY for setting a task to occur on the last day of the month. [More info here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx).

Comment: can you please tell me the function in python? because i dont want to use crontab as well as schtask

Comment: how could that be possible? you would need to have some daemon process running that would check for the date and run your python program if it is that certain date? the only way to "do it in python" would be to use the python process as a deamon itself, which frankly does not make much sense if the operating system provides tools for it.

Comment: @samy the basic idea is to get the today's date and tomorrows's date. If tommorow's date is less than today's its the last day of the month. Uku has done it using linux, if you do not like it you can do the same in python as well.

Comment: This is not python. Try sched.scheduler https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a python solution you could look into [celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Comment: link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no "function in Python" to run code at a specific time. The only way to do it is to have a function running **all the time** that does this. It would look something like this:

```
import calendar
import datetime
import time

def called_last_day():
    print("Hark! It's the last day of the month!")

def running_all_the_time():
    while True:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        if today.day == calendar.month_range(today.year, today.month):
             called_last_day()
        time.sleep(3600) # Wait for an hour
```

So you can do it, but it's a bit daft. Use cron and schtask instead. Really.