# python - how to schedule a function to run at last day of each month?

Tags: python

I want to schedule the function to run at last day of each month using python sched.

can anyone help me for the same?

Comment: Maybe something like cron is more what you're looking for.

Comment: sched is used for scheduling like a cron.

Comment: You can use an OS-specific task-scheduler and configure it to run a Python script with your function in it. How to do the former will depend on your OS and task-scheduler being used. The `sched` module was not designed for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - how to run a function on last day of every month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543971/python-how-to-run-a-function-on-last-day-of-every-month)

Comment: cron on *nix and either AT or the GUI task scheduler on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Run everyday with crontab and check if it is the last day of the month using calendar.monthrange:

```
 import datetime, calendar
 today = datetime.date.today()
 if calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1] != today.day:
     exit()
```

Python [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) and crontab are not in the same league, unless you are talking about another python sched. Windows has a similar scheduller, or you can install cygwin crontab.

If you are in some weird platform that lacks a system wide task scheduller, you can leave an infinite loop running the above test and time.sleep(24*60*60) seconds or something like that.

Comment: If you need an os-specific scheduler (like cron) to schedule once a  day, why not use the scheduler to schedule once a month?

Comment: @Tomas: AFAIK, standard crontab lacks syntax to run in the last day of the month. Running at first day 0:00h is easy, it is almost the same thing as running at the last day 23:59:59.99999h.

Answer (score 1):

Last day of the month has a property that the next date's day value is less than the current one.

Find out how many days are there from the current day to the end of the day. Use the property listed above as the clue. Use `datetime` module for finding the details.

1. Write a function `def mydaycount():` which starts with 0 for the current day and will yield a higher value for each subsequent day. This is similar to your time.time() call but for each day
2. Write a function def mydaydelay(num): which will sleep for a day.

Now, the important part here is the

```
class sched.scheduler(timefunc, delayfunc)
```

The timefunc can be anyfunction which when called returns a value and in your case, it will be the `mydaycount` and delayfunc will be `mydaydelay`.

And then you can call the schduled object with the number of days to the end of the month with action as your action as your function.

```
scheduler.enterabs(time, priority, action, argument)
```

A **rough outline**  for your program would be something like this.

```
import sched
import datetime

def mydaycount():
    yield int_days

def mydaydelay(n):
    sleep_for_days(n)

scheduler = sched.scheduler(mydaycount, mydaydelay)

def print_event(name):
    print 'EVENT:', name

n_days_to_last_day = 3 # This should be your calculate value

scheduler.entertabs(n_days_to_last_day, 1, print_event, ('last day',))

scheduler.run()
```

Comment: calendar.monthrange() will give you the last day of the month, look at http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html.

Comment: @Paulo: Thanks for the note. monthrange() may give the direct value, but the above said thing can definitely be calculated easily using calendar module.