# Updating a column in SQL database table when month changes

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-express

[image]

I am working on fee collection system I need to update the value of the `FeeDue` column when the month changes.

Ex: IF month changed from August to September, `FeeDue` columns needs to be updated

as

```
Value of feedue column = value in fee column + value of feedue column
```

I've tried in many ways but not succeeded

Comment: Use Windows service for automatically update values when come next month .

Comment: try the solutions listed here!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545405/python-how-to-schedule-a-function-to-run-at-last-day-of-each-month

best of luck =]

Comment: RDMBS? table schema? when do you want to update your data? please show some respect when you ask a question!

Comment: If it's a SQL server database, use a scheduled agent job and write the appropriate SQL statement in the job. In addition to @RomanPekar s questions, which part of the update are you having problems with? Is it running it on month end, or actually updating the data?

Comment: running it on month end @pheiberg

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use another query before the month update query to change the feedue.
the other way is to use sql function.

Comment: im not getting logic how my application detects the month change  PLZ HELP

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [SQL Server agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) job which you can customize to run on the start of every month. You can create a procedure which is used to update the values in your required column.

I am **assuming** that you have to run this query once in every month so you dont have to worry about any query logic in your stored procedure regarding months. You can simply create a stored procedure to update the columns in your table. The rest of the job will be done by SQL Server Agent.

A snapshot of the scheduling is below:-

[image]

**NOTE:-** ***This snapshot shows the scheduling at every 3 months. Change that to every month.***

**EDIT:-**

**You can try this to create a job in SQL Server Express Edition:-**

*You can create jobs "manually" by creating batch files and SQL script files, and running them via Windows Task Scheduler.*

**or** You can use [SQL Scheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx)

Comment: How to Customize sql server Agent

Comment: Customize here means you can create a scheduled job that runs at the start of every month :)

Comment: Im using Express Edition(Won't contain sql server Agent) is there any alternative to achieve it Plz Help

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to use a calculated field or just an expression in your select.  You really don't want to be updating all those rows if you can just work it out.  Can you just work out the fee based on number of months outstanding?

Comment: My problem is not about updation how my application detects month change not getting logic PLZ HELP

Answer (score 0):

save the last month you updated feedue in a file and every 24 hour check if it's the next month to update it again.